# Matlab events and listeners: propagate information out of the Event call

Tags: matlab, event-listener, nidaqmx

I have an object that incorporates an event which is created in my program(specifically, a session based ni daq with a 'DataAvailable' event which fires every time a set number of samples is acquired.) This event will be fired at random times during the course of running my program that will do other stuff independent of recording. When fired, it will collect and save the data chunk in a file.

My issue is that everytime the Event is triggered, i need to increase a counter (i name it "chunk") in my original program. This is critical as a number of features in my program depend on my being able to measure the number of chunks accurately.

QUESTION: how can i propagate the fact that an event has been triggered into my main program?

For people who process (pseudo)code better:

```
setupStuff();
endLoop = false;
while ~endLoop
  if ~recording
    session  = createDAQSessionObject(params);
    chunkNum = 0;
    session.addListener('DataAvailable',@(src,event)saveChunk(src,event,chunkNum));
    session.startBackGround()
    recording  = true;
  end
  endLoop = doOtherStuff();
  pause(0.1);
end

function saveChunk(src,event,numChunk)
  filename = sprintf('chunk%d.mat',numChunk);
  times = event.TimeStamps;
  data = event.Data;
  save(filename,'times','data');
  % but now the next time around we need to get in numChunks+1 (but we never will because we have no way of knowing that the event was called...
end
```

Thanks

-bas

Comment: `global numChunk`? or `persistent numChunk`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html

Comment: Define your main program as handle class, and pass the object to saveChunk. Since objects of class handle are passed by reference, you'll have the correct count anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`global`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) or [`persistent`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) does the job in this minimal example -

1. Define a class to be the event source.

   ```
   classdef bar < handle
       events
           sayhello
       end
   end
   ```
2. Build a function that uses a persistent variable `num`. `num` is visible only to function `foo`, but it is "persistent" between calls to `foo`. It remains in `foo`'s workspace until `clear all` is excecuted, or Matlab quits.

   ```
   function foo(~,~)
   persistent num
   if isempty(num)
       num = 1;
   else
       num = num+1;
   end
   fprintf('hi %d\n', num);
   end
   ```

   .... and call it from main script

   ```
   bigjob = bar;
   addlistener(bigjob, 'sayhello', @foo);

   for ii = 1:10
       notify(bigjob, 'sayhello')
   end
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   hi 1
   hi 2
   hi 3
   hi 4
   hi 5
   hi 6
   hi 7
   hi 8
   hi 9
   hi 10
   >>
   ```
3. Build another function that uses a global variable `num`. `num` is kept in base workspace, visible to all functions as well as the main script, and is alive until `clear global num` is called or Matlab quits.

   ```
   function foo(~,~)
   global num
   num = num+1;
   fprintf('hi %d\n', num);
   end
   ```

   .... and change the script to declare and *initialize* the global `num`

   ```
   global num
   num = 0;
   bigjob = bar;
   addlistener(bigjob, 'sayhello', @foo);

   for ii = 1:10
       notify(bigjob, 'sayhello')
   end
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   hi 1
   hi 2
   hi 3
   hi 4
   hi 5
   hi 6
   hi 7
   hi 8
   hi 9
   hi 10
   >>
   ```

### Efficiency concerns

Using `global` or `persistent` is costly. I changed my code to `ii = 50000`, and muted the `fprintf`, to perform a benchmark.

According to Profiler, using `global` takes ~10% of total running time; by "using `global`" I mean declaring `global num` in function `foo`.

.... while using `persistent` takes ~25% of total running time (it adds up to the total, so running `persistent` is slower than `global`); by "using `persistent`" I mean these lines

```
persistent num
if isempty(num)
else
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that this wont be necessary. Is there any understanding about who calls the listener function? Is it in the same thread? What happens when the original function is in the process of doing other things? Does it stop that and do the listen event? Or does matlab spool another process?

Comment: @bas To identify the caller, you can add a caller id as an event argument. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-events.html#f90010

Comment: @bas check this documentation for DAQ http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/examples/generate-continuous-and-background-signals-using-ni-devices.html

Comment: thanks. that was useful. my current strategy: subclass a session with a public proeprty called chunkNum. and in the listener event modify the chunkNum everytime the event is fired! I'll keep this post updated as I progress.